# How to print p:tree or p:treeTable in primefaces using java in tree structure?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have implemented dynamic tree using p:tree in java. As mentioned here on [link](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/basic.xhtml) primefaces showcase.

Now I want to print it in the tree structure.

Comment: If you want to do it in prime faces, I mean from the UI please follow the below document, https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/basic.xhtml

Comment: primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/basic.xhtml  which tag to use I tried <p:printer target="image" /> but it did not work as expected. No feature to set zoom level and scrolled data is cropped and not in printed pdf. Can you be more precise on how to do it. Thanks @Arun Prasat

Comment: This might not be the exact solution you are looking for but I had same problem once and I decided to use iText to print the tree structure. It was simple if..else logic to provide proper indention between node and leaf.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking going for iText atlast :). What I wanted was some automatic process to printout the tree from p:tree.

Comment: Sanyam, I don't think there is any process like that to my knowledge.